# Single word for quiz competition participant

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who is interested in / regularly participate in quiz competitions (e.g. pub trivia nights)?

A sample sentence: *My skills: Web development, UX design, (**quiz wiz?**)*, ...

Comment: The participant is called a contestant.

Comment: @deadrat, thank you I know about contestant. Can you think of some other word that reflects the persons skill or keen interest in participating and winning quizzes?

Comment: Sorry, but perhaps someone knows a suitable BrE word for a fan of pub quiz nights. Don't all the participants want to win?

Comment: @deadrat If you want a British word, I'd use **punter**: "*chiefly British :  customer, patron*". This refers mite specifically to the regular patrons of a pub: those most likely to join in with such games.

Comment: Hi Tony, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. You must include **a sample sentence** demonstrating how the word would be used." [My emphasis]. You can add these details by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: You might also like to clarify whether you mean participation in "live" competitions (e.g. pub trivia nights, or TV million-dollar-quiz shows), or the kind of competition where you write or email or upload your answer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't get closer than ***quizzer***.

Curiously there is no definition in any dictionary and most only state it being a derivation from quiz, but ODO has several example sentences. From these sentences it seems quite fitting to your needs.

> ‘The quizmaster went back a happy man despite the turnout, as this was ‘a focused bunch of *quizzers*, who answered most queries’.’
>
> ‘Needless to say, young *quizzers* are encouraged.’
>
> ‘Nobody likes a clever-clogs, however, especially not on television and so many of the *quizzers* play strategically dumb during the audition process in order to increase the sense of dramatic tension.’
>
> ‘She sits back in her garden chair, turning away from the *quizzer*.’  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quizzer)

Comment: quizzer was my first thought, but after seeing this http://www.mnemonicdictionary.com/word/quizzer I was a bit confused

Comment: @TonyVincent I trust the ODO over some random Indian company.

Answer (score 1):

A **contestant** would fit. It connotes a more formal quiz competition.

> A person who is involved in an activity or event : a person who participates in an activity or event

Answer (score 0):

How about Competitive? It means a person who has keen interest in joining and winning any competitions in general though, not only quizzes.

Comment: Or a Whiz, alternatively wiz. According to the freedictionary it's an informal term for someone who is particularly skilled at a specific field. For example a math whiz, or a computer wiz/whiz. So I hope it's also safe to say, 'quiz wiz'.